# Accessing Models in Node.js using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model, require

I'm new to node.js and am not entirely sure how to access models in my `app.js` file.  My file structure is as follows:

```
- controllers 
- helpers 
- middlewares
- models 
- node_modules 
- public 
- tests 
- views 
app.js 
package.json
```

## App.js

Within my `app.js` I have:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var models = require('./models'); 


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {title: 'Mosaic Viewer'}); 
}); 

app.get('/map', function(req, res){
    var blockMosaicStreamer = models.BlockMosaicStreamer(); 
    res.render('view', {type: "block", name: "Sara", latitude: "", longitude: "", zoom: ""}); 
}); 

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Mosaic Tile Server listening on port 3000...'); 
});
```

When I try `var models = require('./models')` I get:

> Error: Cannot find module './models'

I'm really new to this so I think it may just be a conceptual misunderstanding.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Does your `models` folder contain a file `index.js`? And does this file export all the models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get this line

```
var models = require('./models')
```

working you need to create ./models/index.js file with following content:

```
module.exports = {
// your model's code
};
```

You can read more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)